# SQLite warning automatic index on SubQuery

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have the following SQL

```
SELECT *
FROM Genres, GenreImages 
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT SUM(Movies.PlayCount) AS SummedPlayCounts, MovieGenres.GenreId 
FROM Movies, MovieGenres 
WHERE Movies.Id = MovieGenres.MovieId 
GROUP BY MovieGenres.GenreId 
ORDER BY SummedPlayCounts DESC) AS GenreMoviesPlayCounts 
ON GenreMoviesPlayCounts.GenreId = Genre.Id 
WHERE GenreImages.GenreId = Genres.Id 
AND GenreImages.PrimaryImage = 1
```

it throws

```
SQLite warning (284): automatic index on sqlite_sq_BD26FF8(GenreId)
```

`MovieGenres.GenreId` does have an index, as does `GenreImages.GenreId`.  This warning is coming from the subquery `GenreMoviesPlayCounts.GenreId = Genre.Id`.

Is there a better way to do this that makes use of my existing index or doesn't need a sub query?

Comment: That depends on the details of the database schema.

Comment: @CL. what details?

Comment: Show the database schema.